# Samsung smart-TV javascript app security

Tags: javascript, security, console, samsung-smart-tv

Tried searching a lot for this, no luck so far. Maybe someone has an idea about it, that would be appreciated. When deploying a javascript/html app to the TV (SAMSUNG), is the code compiled somehow? Can the user crawl into the code and change it? ( like doing with google chrome debugger ). I need some form of security / validation that is client sided, but I'm new with this and not sure if it's safe. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

> is the code compiled somehow?

JavaScript is a runtime scripting language. It does not require compiling.

> Can the user crawl into the code and change it?

Apparently there are JS consoles available, and the user might be able to use them to set up breakpoints or run JS commands on them using these. See:

- http://forums.boxee.tv/showthread.php?t=47754
- http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00111/index.html
- http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

Perhaps you might want to start another question discussing your app and asking about the possible security options.